# I Have Couple of Questions Regarding Graduation

Tags: discussion, support

I have couple of questions regarding our community site's graduation.

1. When will we graduate? Is there any specific date for this?
2. What would be the name of our site?
3. Is there any procedure to select the name of graduating site?
4. After the completion of graduation process, are we able to add or remove topic that should be discussed (on-topic) here??

   Comment or answer your opinions. Thanks

Comment: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/633/its-election-and-graduation-eve?cb=1

Comment: @benmarks I know about that thread. But there is no hint about "date". I couldn't find answers of all of my questions there :(

Comment: I don't understand question #4, can you clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **When will we graduate? Is there any specific date for this?**

   Graduation is a multi-step process, so it has happened but is ongoing:

   > when your election starts, you'll be the first site that gets to try out this new "graduation without design" approach...
   >
   > - you will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name (✓)
   > - you will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network (✓)
   > - you will be able to select your own community ads (✓)

   Final date (when all things would be complete) is known only to StackExchange and most likely subject to their design backlog.
2. **What would be the name of our site?**
3. **Is there any procedure to select the name of graduating site?**

   I think you are asking what the URL will be. [Most SE sites use a topic.stackexchange.com format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), and there's no reason to think that this site would be different (e.g. mageoverflow.com). Seems like [determination of this is historical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124327/whats-the-eligibility-criteria-for-a-se-site-to-get-dedicated-domain-name#comment332729_124327). If we want to clamor for a custom domain, now's the time. [See the discussion on this answer for precedent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126264/188727).
4. **Can we update/remove on-topic/off-topic here during graduation?**

   If I understand correctly, you're asking if there is flexibility as to what is on- or off-topic. Unless I'm mistaken, that can happen at anytime. Best to just start a thread in Meta.

Comment: thanks ben for your clarification. i edited my question and let me know its answer

Comment: Responded to your edit.

Comment: splendid. Thanks

Comment: also @marius pointed out one of his tweet that area51 still shows we are in beta? Do u know why it is so?

Comment: Just chiming in here to say that Ben's got it right. One note about #4, though: _technically_ we could make changes at any time but in practice we find that earlier = better. By the time a site graduates, we generally expect that its community will have already settled on the scope it'll be comfortable with permanently. Figuring that stuff out is kinda one of the main purposes of having a beta period. cc @RajeevKTomy

Comment: @Pops thanks for the official confirmation from your side. about #4 point, how can we do that. may be a meta question to propose new topic would be sufficient?? Or is there any other way of doing this ??

Comment: @RajeevKTomy you're exactly right, gathering strong support on meta is an important step in this case. If you have a new topic in mind (and it sounds like you do) then throw a new meta question out there and make your case to the community.

Comment: @Pops also could you please make a clarification on beta label in area51. if we're graduated, then why that page. still shows we are in beta ??

Comment: Area 51 is a little behind on getting updated to our new way of doing things. Its design still uses our old assumption that graduation is something that happens all at once. Since we haven't thrown all the graduation switches on this site yet, A51 doesn't recognize its status. We are planning to update the system there, but it's a [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/) sort of project.